# Can anyone tell me what causes that white space appear between the contact form and the footer?

Tags: html, footer

I have written the html but the contact form is copied from a another place...and I cant get rid of that white line no matter what I do.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

NOTE: here it is, on jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/j6RMW/embedded/result/
or
http://jsfiddle.net/j6RMW/

There the white space is gone....but you can see the screenshot that it is actually there.

NOTE2: this is what causes the problem...it is html issue:

```
<form name="freecontactform" method="post" action="freecontactformprocess.php" onsubmit="return validate.check(this)">
<table width="400px" class="freecontactform">
<tbody><tr>
 <td colspan="2">

 <div class="freecontactformheader">Contacto</div>

 <div class="freecontactformmessage">Fields marked with <span class="required_star"> * </span> are mandatory.</div>

 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Full_Name" class="required">Nombre/apellidos<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="Full_Name" id="Full_Name" maxlength="80" style="width:230px">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Email_Address" class="required">Email<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="Email_Address" id="Email_Address" maxlength="100" style="width:230px">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Telephone_Number" class="not-required">Número de telefono</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="Telephone_Number" id="Telephone_Number" maxlength="100" style="width:230px">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Your_Message" class="required">Tu mensaje<span class="required_star"> * </span></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea style="width:230px;height:160px" name="Your_Message" id="Your_Message" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="antispammessage">
  To help prevent automated spam, please answer this question
  <br><br>
      <div class="antispamquestion">
       <span class="required_star"> * </span>
       Using only numbers, what is 10 plus 15? &nbsp; 
       <input type="text" name="AntiSpam" id="AntiSpam" maxlength="100" style="width:30px">
      </div>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value=" Submit Form " style="width:200px;height:40px">
  <br><br>
  <br><br>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

I am new to this. Thanks for the info so far...and I'll keep this updated and let you guys know if I can sort it out on my own.

Comment: Provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). There's not enough to go off in your question.

Comment: Unlikely with so little information. Upload full css and html for the contact form, either here or at jsfiddle.net, where it can be viewed and edited online.

Comment: @flem done...uploaded it...the link is in the main message.

Comment: It works fine in your fiddle. That is not help at all, sorry!

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to investigate the issue. Pressing F12 in most browsers should get you to the dev tools. From there, you should be able to target the white space and view the CSS/markup that causes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your  tag to this

```
<form name="freecontactform" method="post" action="freecontactformprocess.php" onsubmit="return validate.check(this)" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
```

Because it is inline CSS this takes over any external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome right mouse click on the space and click inspect element. if there isn't an option to select element right mouse click on your form and go from there.

You should have a window at the bottom of your screen now, using the window where it is now showing you are HTML, find the white block in the HTML code by hovering your mouse over the HTML tags. If you can't find the white block find you  tag and go from there.

If you haver over your form tag you should see it highlighted on the above screen. If the white block is highlighted when you are hovering over the  you know it is a CSS property in your stylesheet, if it isn't highlighted then it has nothing to do with your  and something else is putting it there. Repete the steps till you find the tag that highlights the white block.

Once you find it look at the 'styles' section on the right of the bottom section of the screen. Go through the styles connected to that tag and tick them off one by one till the block goes. Then you know what CSS property is effecting it.

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, here is the problem. The contact form has 2 different things..one is called the "table" and the other one is called the "table.freecontactform".

The "form" is 687*590 pixel, whine the "table" is 580*590 pixels. I have no clue where to set the form to 580*590 too. That way the white stripe would disappear.

Comment: Did you use the Chrome inspect element feature? If so look to the right when the inspecter window is showing, in the Matched CSS rules section it should show you the CSS properties. It should show the stylesheet it is looking to for the properties (The underlined line on the right next to each style). It will also give you the line number too. eg style.css:10 That is in the stye stylesheet on line 10. You should see your height and width properties there and change them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but eventually I just got rid of the <form> and </form> lines..and left the whole thing in as <table></table>.

Comment: Not advised to do that, there are <form> tags for a reason. And considering you are going to be passing the data to freeContactForm.php it will be easier to use the form submit functions. Do you have this page live somewhere other than on jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, I have just experienced that all the functions are gone. :) 
I have just found that I need to change the width in the properties and within that it is the HTMLinputElement....the problems is that I have no clue where that is. :(

Comment: Ah, the page is here: gaberivers.com/contactar.html